# Do you get paid more if your notice period ends on bank holiday/weekend in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, legal-terms

I consider leaving my current job in UK and wanted to ask about the following situation. I work in UK, my contract is indefinite and my notice period is 3 months. Let say I hand in my resignation today, then my last day of work would be Thursday 22nd of December (23rd?). However, in 2016, the 24th, 25th, 26th and 27th of December 2016 are not working days (weekend + 2 bank holidays).

Does it mean that if I hand in my notice on the 27th of September I will get paid for extra 4 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, months in English law means calendar months.